# validate color(hexadecimal value) using .net data annotations

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I need validate model variable color in MVC using data annotations. it should be a hexadecimal value. how to validate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `RegularExpression` data annotation attribute, like below:

```
[RegularExpression("^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Format")]
public string Color { get; set; }
```